# How can i only show the header on some pages and not all of them

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a _header.html.erb rendering in all my pages from layouts/applications. Is there a way that i can not make it show on some pages? For example i would like the header not to show in example.com/videos/1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in your layout file:

```
<% unless @hide_header %>
   <%= render 'header' %>
<% end %>
```

And then set `@hide_header = true` in your controller if you want it to be hidden.

Comment: One-liner: `<%= render 'header' unless @hide_header %>`